# Analyzing data for noisy arrays

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Using MATLAB I filtered a very noisy m x n array with a low-pass Gaussian filter, cleaned it up pretty well but still not well enough to analyze my data. What would the next step be? I'm thinking that signal enhancement, but am not sure how to go about this.

**Update**

Well, there are two different types of data sets actually; one is small peaks circular at base, around half a dozen pixels wide at base, noisy background with random noise. The other is the same thing but Gaussian and Poisson noise mainly. I tried filtering w/Gaussian low pass in both instances, worked to some extent as mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to answer this without knowing what data you have, and what the noise is like.
Different problems will have different best solutions.